# new Akka I/O (Java) TCP data processing using ByteIterator need a java example if possible

Tags: java, tcp, io, akka

I'm trying to implement a Tcp server using the new Akka I/O, unfortunately the documentation is not yet finished, and i'm having some issues implementing it in java :(.
I managed to create a client and server and to send a message from the client to the server,
but how do you read the recieved bytes using the ByteIterator?
am i having the wrong appreach? maybe that's not how you process the data.

something weird happens when i send alot of messages very fast, they are all queued to the bi, and the data is never reset event after I make a it.getInt()

```
 if (msg instanceof Tcp.Received) {
   final Tcp.Received recv = (Tcp.Received) msg;
   final ByteString data = recv.data();
   ByteIterator bi = data.iterator();
   while(bi.hasNext()) {
      ....
   }
 } else if (msg instanceof Tcp.CommandFailed) {
   final Tcp.CommandFailed failed = (Tcp.CommandFailed) msg;
   final Tcp.Command command = failed.cmd();
   // react to failed connect, bind, write, etc.
 } else if (msg instanceof Tcp.ConnectionClosed) {
   final Tcp.ConnectionClosed closed = (Tcp.ConnectionClosed) msg;
   if (closed.isAborted()) {
      // handle close reasons like this
 }
```

Solution:
Oh! now I understand my mistake, I cached the byteStringBuilder on the client, and forgot to clear it -_- how stupid !

for those who will want an example of implementation for Java here is how I did it:

if you guys have any optimizations im taking em !:)

```
   int packetSize = 0;
   if (msg instanceof Tcp.Received) {
        final Tcp.Received recv = (Tcp.Received) msg;
        final ByteString data = recv.data();
        ByteIterator bi = data.iterator();
        while (bi.hasNext()) {
            packetSize = bi.getInt(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
            Message m = Message.fromByteIterator(bi);
            getContext().parent().tell(m, null);
        }

    }
```

Message.fromByteIterator(bi) will just intialize a new Message Object by taking Ints, Floats, Bytes Arrays ... from the BI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure that I understand the problem, but there are two issues that might have caused the problem here.

The ByteString that you receive contains the chunk that was delivered by Tcp. The iterator you get on that will only iterate on that chunk. It is not a stream, only a chunk. Also, Tcp can decide to split your stream of bytes wherever it wants, so the chunks you get might be not aligned with your message boundaries. You have to handle framing yourself.

The second issue can happen if you are sending too fast and the network can't keep up. Akka IO has built-in flow control mechanisms for that. The simplest case is to attach an Ack object on each Write and only send the next write if the previous one has been acked.

Comment: when i send the data very fast from many clients, the server enters the while(it.hasNext()) loop and loops over the same data again and again with some additional adata after each loop 
ex :
I send : hello1 , then hello2 then hello3, then hello4

On the server i recieve:
hello1
then
hello1/hello2
then 
hello1/hello2/hello3
then hello1/hello2/hello3/hello4

everytime the iterator iterates over already treated data, it's really weird

Comment: Glad that you solved it! In the meantime there is work going on that will make such processing easier via pipelines similar to what Spray does.